# Google Chrome Extension onclick alert function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to develop a extension but this is getting in my way.
This is my manisfest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version":2,
    "name":"erp",
    "version":"1.0",
    "permissions":["storage"],
    "browser_action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    }
}
```

This is my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script scr="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="username"></textarea><br>
    <!--<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
    <input type="button" id="show" value="Show saved Data">-->
    <input type="button" id='save' value="Save"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my popup.js

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(){
        var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
        alert(user);
}}
```

Although there is nothing to alert. Please help.

Comment: Are you getting empty alert or no alert at all?

Comment: Why error you get in your console?

Comment: I m simply not getting any alert and error also. The chrome console some how shows some error but i beleive those are not related to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just misspelled the `src` attribute.

Your Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script scr="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="username"></textarea><br>
    <!--<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
    <input type="button" id="show" value="Show saved Data">-->
    <input type="button" id='save' value="Save"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Correct Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="username"></textarea><br>
    <!--<input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
    <input type="button" id="show" value="Show saved Data">-->
    <input type="button" id='save' value="Save"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing i don't know why the username is in textarea?

If you have an empty alert please notice that textarea has a different behavior to input in their value.

```
<input type="text" value="value">
```

but textarea is not like this:

```
<textarea id="username">value</textarea>
```

But both works in javascript by 'value' property as you write.

And if you have **no alert** i must say that your code is true(I tested) and you have a problem before this:
`window.onload = func...`

Put an alert before to see if it works or not:

```
alert('Code is true until here');
window.onload = func...
```

Comment: Its not showing the alert of the beginning lie also as u said to tried.